# How to cache Lucene search result?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I looking for solution how to cache searching results in Lucene.
When i used Solr pagination was much easier

My solr code:

> query.setStart(start);
>   query.setRows(rows);
>   QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);

Simple wildcard searching it was like 400ms for 1st 100 results and each next page it was like 20-70ms

But when I'm using Lucene each time I have to search again and each page takes 400ms

My Lucene code:

> Query query = queryParser.parse(text);
>
> TopScoreDocCollector collector=TopScoreDocCollector.create(1000000);
>    IndexSearcher = indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
>
> TopDocs results =collector.topDocs(start,rows);
>           for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : results.scoreDocs) {
>               Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);

I tried make TopScoreDocCollector and IndexSearcher static but this don't work

Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I made results static

> static TopDocs results;
>
> results = indexSearcher.search(query, 100000);
>
> public ArrayList meakeResult() throws IOException{
>         ArrayList res = new ArrayList();
>
> ScoreDoc[] hits=results.scoreDocs;
>
> ```
>    for (int i=start; i < start+rows; i++) {
>        Document document = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
>        Answer tab = new Answer();
>        tab.setAnswer(document.get("answer"));
>        tab.setQuestion("question" + document.get("question"));
>        tab.setProces("proces" + document.get("proces"));
>        tab.setForm("form: " + document.get("form")); 
>        res.add(tab);
>    }
> ```

Comment: This solutions is flawed in a multi-threaded (web-application context) environment. There should be another way to achieve this: static is not a real "fix" for your problem.